# Google Maps loadGeoJSON getGeometry.get() latlng disappear

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Working through this tutorial from Google: https://developers.google.com/codelabs/maps-platform/google-maps-simple-store-locator

Github code here: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/google-maps-simple-store-locator

file: app.js
functions: initMap(), calculateDistances();

My specific issue is that the latlng properties get lost somewhere. The map loads and all the map points load. However when I use the search/autocomplete the map.data is passed as parameter through this function (line 218)

```
const rankedStores = await calculateDistances(map.data, originLocation);
```

and is parsed with this function (line 234)

```
async function calculateDistances(data, origin) {
   const stores = [];
   const destinations = []
  // Build parallel arrays for the store IDs and destinations
  data.forEach((store) => {
     const storeNum = store.getProperty('storeid');
     const storeLoc = store.getGeometry().get();
     console.log(storeLoc);
     stores.push(storeNum);
     destinations.push(storeLoc);
});
```

in the console.log no geometries appear. the objects and respective latlng properties are there just not the actual coordinates. when I view the storeNum in console. they display as they should. I have verified the coordinates exist in jSON and they map points prove that the map.data.loadGeoJSON is working correctly. I am just going crazy trying to find where the coordinates went and how to ensure they get passed to the calculateDistances function. Any help is appreciated.

Screenshot A:
[image: screenshot A console.log(store.storeLoc)]

Screenshot B:

[image: screenshot B console.log(store.toUrlValue(6))]

Comment: What do you mean by the "coordinates are not there"?  What do you get if you do `console.log(storeLoc.toUrlValue(6))`?

Comment: @geocodezip I got the coordinates in the screenshot B above. Screenshot A is an example of what I meant when coordinate values in the object were not there.

Comment: The coordinates are there.  You need to call the `lat()` function to get the latitude, the `lng()` function to get the longitude (or `toUrlValue()` to get a comma separated string containing both).

Comment: @geocodezip confirmed. console.log(storeLoc.lat()) does print out so this answers the question. Could you please write an answer so I can mark as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the coordinates from a [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng) object (which is what is returned by [store.getGeometry().get()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.Point.get)), use the `.lat()` function for latitude, the `.lng()` function for longitude, or the `.toUrlValue()` function for a comma separated string containing both.

```
async function calculateDistances(data, origin) {
   const stores = [];
   const destinations = []
  // Build parallel arrays for the store IDs and destinations
  data.forEach((store) => {
     const storeNum = store.getProperty('storeid');
     const storeLoc = store.getGeometry().get();
     console.log(storeLoc.toUrlValue(6));
     stores.push(storeNum);
     destinations.push(storeLoc);
});
```